# why the output window cannot display the result. Image processing - line detection

Tags: c++, image-processing, straight-line-detection

this Hough Transform program is supposed to display the source image, output image, edge detection results windows with images when executed.
However, the output image window is not displaying anything even though the source image and edge detection results
the link https://github.com/eToTheEcs/hough-transform/blob/master/hough.cpp

Comment: Hi Jyohong, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm having trouble understanding the language of your question. Could you please use the usual language rules like capitalization, punctuation, like ending sentences with full stops, use quotes etc. Here on SO, it also helps to keep sentences as short as possible. The question must be completely understandable without having to follow any links. See stackoverflow.com/help/asking in general. The point is to make it easy for the readers. What exactly did you try? What happened? What did you expect?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.